# Connecting ipv4 client to ipv4 server through ipv6?

Tags: networking, ipv6, ipv4

Does someone know if it is possible to connect an ipv4 client to an ipv4 server through ipv6, by means of "IPv4 over IPv6" (encapsulation known as MAP-E)?

If if is, what would be the requirements for that connection? Would two routers supporting MAP-E on both connection endpoints be enough ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible for two IPv4 endpoints to communicate over an IPv6 network. Typically, the connection between two routers has no regard for the private endpoint networks and is completely transparent to the end points. The endpoints will not see what protocol is being used to route their traffic.

Comment: Yes, but IPv6 encapsulation from IPV4 should be done somewhere, I believe the router would do that, right? What are the hardware requirements for an ipv6 connection between 2 ipv4 clients ?

Comment: It is done on the router, but these things only affect the WAN interfaces.